# Want in a html email a div with two colors

Tags: html, outlook, html-table, html-email

I want to have in a, e-mail that I code in HTML, a div with two colors and a text in span.

I have coded this:

```
<div class="msg" style=" width: 500px; background-color: gray; position: relative;">
<span class="text" style="font-size: 11px; color: white; position: absolute; bottom: 5px; left: 1%;">A text in a span.</span>
<div class="refus" style="width: 50%; height: 25px; background-color: #EF4135"></div>
</div>
```

You can find a demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/aWvcp/2/

The problem is, in an mail tool like Thunderbird, it's working but not in outlook.

Is it possible to have the same render but for compatible with Outlook?

Comment: HTML email messages are one of the most annoying things in modern digital communication. They are a huge security thread which means you request ultimate trust from the receivers. In other words: everyone who is concerned about security in any way must delete your message without reading it or he risk a security flaw. Because of that html email messages are considered a bad style of communication: aggressive and overly complex without any need. Don't send such messages.

Comment: I need to send this message because the customer want the type of the message with some charts ;-).

Comment: In that case send a normal text message with a link to a web page where the information is presented. Also most likely the customer is not aware of the security threads he risks. You should inform him.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure strictest adherence to your design, I would avoid `<DIV>`s, CSS position statements and spans. Be as regimented as possible with tables, inline margin tags and `<p>` with inline style. See a recreation of what you wanted in [JSfillde](http://jsfiddle.net/AJGiliana/aWvcp/10/).

Comment: Thanks
Yes i have tested a solution with table too but the issue is the text. If the text is too long to be in the column1, the column1 will be "fat", too high.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell exactly what you are after, but here is an example in proper html email format:

```
<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%" bgcolor="#EF4135" valign="bottom" style="font-size: 11px; color: white; padding:1%; padding-bottom:5px;">
      First column<br>...<br>...
    </td>
    <td valign="top" width="50%">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td height="25" bgcolor="#818181">
            &nbsp;
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```